# Días de diferencia entre dos fecha SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Cree una tabla en la cual solo tengo las fechas con los días hábiles del año y necesito sacar la diferencia, en días hábiles, entre dos fechas.

La tabla de días hábiles de abril es:

```
    SELECT FECHA 
    FROM AR_FECHA
    WHERE MONTH(FECHA) = 4
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, cómo saber la diferencia en días hábiles entre el día de hoy, 17 de abril

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Con la última fecha del mes de Abril (7 días).

Comment: [DateDiff](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: En ese caso, o no está bien explicada la pregunta o yo no te entendí. Te refieres a la diferencia de indices entre dos fechas de tu tabla? Si es así, deberías tener un indice para cada entrada y simplemente restar

Comment: Si, debe de ser de mi tabla que solo contiene los días hábiles por eso agrego el resultado del mes de Abril, el resultado que espero es de 7 días habiles, usando el DATEDIFF seria de 13 días naturales

Comment: Como te he dicho,en ese caso simplemente añade un campo de indic e a tu tabla ar_fecha si no lo tienes ya,y resta esas columnas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edición**

Luego de los comentarios, he entendido que lo que quieres es obtener el número de días hábiles entre dos fechas, basado en tu tabla de días hábiles.

Para ello, lo que puedes hacer es simplemente, en un CTE, numerar los días en la tabla y luego obtener la diferencia entre ese índice de días entre las dos fechas que te interesan.

Por ejemplo, para obtener la diferencia entre la fecha actual y el 30 de abril de 2019, podrías escribir un *query* como este:

```
with
C1 as (
select Fecha, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Fecha) NumeroDiaHabil
  from ar_fecha
)
select   Fecha.Fecha , FechaCalculo.NumeroDiaHabil - Fecha.NumeroDiaHabil  DiasHabilesDiferencia
  from C1 FechaCalculo
       cross join C1 Fecha
 where FechaCalculo.Fecha = '20190430'
   and Fecha.Fecha = CAST(getdate() as date);
```

Que, con tus datos de entrada, arrojaría este resultado:

```
Fecha      DiasHabilesEntre
---------- --------------------
2019-04-17 7

(1 row affected)
```

O podrías generalizarlo para obtener la diferencia entre una fecha específica y cualquier otra fecha de tu tabla, por ejemplo, este query:

```
with
C1 as (
select Fecha, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Fecha) NumeroDiaHabil
  from ar_fecha
)
select   Fecha.Fecha
       , FechaCalculo.NumeroDiaHabil - Fecha.NumeroDiaHabil  DiasHabilesEntre
  from C1 FechaCalculo
       cross join C1 Fecha
 where FechaCalculo.Fecha = '20190430'
   and month(Fecha.Fecha) = 4;
```

Arrojaría el siguiente resultado:

```
Fecha      DiasHabilesEntre
---------- --------------------
2019-04-01 19
2019-04-02 18
2019-04-03 17
2019-04-04 16
2019-04-05 15
2019-04-08 14
2019-04-09 13
2019-04-10 12
2019-04-11 11
2019-04-12 10
2019-04-15 9
2019-04-16 8
2019-04-17 7
2019-04-22 6
2019-04-23 5
2019-04-24 4
2019-04-25 3
2019-04-26 2
2019-04-29 1
2019-04-30 0

(20 rows affected)
```

## Respuesta original

Puedes utilizar la función [`DateDiff`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas. La función puede sacar la diferencia en años, trimestres, meses, días, horas, minutos, etc.

Para sacar la diferencia de hoy con todas las fechas de tu tabla, haz esta consulta:

```
select fecha, getdate(), datediff(day, getdate(), fecha) DiasDiferencia
  from ar_fecha
 where month(fecha) = 4;
```

Comment: Por alguna razón no me esta tomando las fecha que tengo en mi tabla AR_FECHA me esta mostrando la diferencia de 13 días naturales y no de 7 días habiles

Comment: No comprendo entonces, cuál es el resultado que deseas obtener?

Comment: En la imagen que muestro en la parte de arriba solo muestra días hábiles, del días de hoy 17/04/2019 para llegar al 30/04/2019 son 7 días

Comment: Sugiero que edites tu pregunta, para dejar en claro lo que buscas, y yo editaré mi respuesta para que puedas calcularlo. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo, he editado mi respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

No se si te funcione pero en sql sever 2008 para sacar la diferencia de días se ocupa el DATEDIFF

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), '2019-04-18');
```

Retornaría 1 Día de diferencia

Answer (score 0):

Segun tu comentario: seleccionar la última fecha del mes de abril y comparala con la fecha actual.

```
select datediff(day, getdate(), fecha) DiasDiferencia from ar_fecha where month(fecha) = 4 order by fecha desc;
```